# How to open all modified files with git?

Tags: git, bash, vim, awk

How to open all deleted, modified, and created files since the last git commit, I tried using `git status` first, but it was difficult to parse, so I found `git status --porcelain` was easier to parse and with awk + vim + some bash magic it was easy to do.

Comment: What does it even mean to open a deleted file?

Comment: eg: `a.rb` was deleted, `vim a.rb` will open an empty file, saving it will create a blank file, not doing anything will be useful to just notice that the file was deleted

Answer (score 39, accepted):

So, I found the solution with `vim`:

```
vim $(git status --porcelain | awk '{print $2}')
```

And I post this question + answer just to answer it myself and share it to the internet

Comment: Backticks are deprecated

Comment: @HolgerJust You have cited an answer on this stie, which doesn't really prove anything. But regardless, even if not deprecated, they are obsolete and have absolutely no advantage on `$()` whereas `$()` has many advantages on them. The only reason to ever use them is for compatibility with a old Bourne Shells.Also if you read the top comment for that post, i am of the same opinion.

Comment: IDK, I just find backticks are shorter and easier to write, but yes, `$()` seems more readable

Comment: Try `git ls-files -o -m --exclude-standard` as git command. It includes new files and does not require awk step.

Comment: alternative to @ruuter's command `git diff HEAD --name-only` lists cached and uncached changes

Comment: `vim $(git status --porcelain -s | awk '{print $2}')` When you are in sub folder.

Answer (score 9):

In order for this to work when im in a sub folder of the git repo i just use the -s option to git status. Vim option -O opens the files in vertical split.

`vim -O $(git status -s | awk '{print $2}')`

Comment: You'd want to user the `-p` flag instead of `-O` in the vim command to open them in tabs, because if you have more than 2 modified files your vim screen will be clustered with divisions.

Comment: This is much handy!

Answer (score 8):

From this [blog](http://josephhsu.com/post/2582726215/open-all-modified-files-tracked-by-git-in-default), you can edit `~/.gitconfig` and add this line:

```
[alias]
  edit = !$EDITOR $(git status --short | awk '$1 ~ /^M|A|U/ {print $2}' )
```

Now, `git edit` will open all modified files

Comment: Using `--porcelain` is probably better, because the output will be the same no matter your config, ...

Comment: @edi9999 `--porcelain` is not relative to the current working directory, which may be a valid reason to use `--short` instead.

Comment: +1 for git alias, but for git command I would rather use `git ls-files -o -m --exclude-standard`, which also includes new files and does not require awk step.

Comment: I used `!$EDITOR $(git d $1 --name-only)` as an alias, which will let you open files differing from other named branches, or to HEAD if left blank

Answer (score 5):

```
git ls-files --modified --deleted --others -z | xargs -0 vim
```

Comment: I get tons of files from `tmp/` that are in my `.gitignore`

Comment: I would suggest `git ls-files -o -m --exclude-standard` to open modified and new files, but exclude ignored. Also, for me the `xargs` solution does not work with vim (it pipes all file names as one string to vim as a new file and blocks terminal input), while `vim $()` works nicely.